# Converting a string in a hexa with 21 chars

Tags: c#, java, c++, bit-manipulation, shift

I have a service to integrate with another application, and it accept just 21 hexa chars. I need to pass and recieve a string with 11 decimal chars, for sample: `String s = "0101230154V";`

I would like to know, how could I use the shift operations to convert it in bits and transmit, because I cannot convert my decimal string to hexa because it will result in 22 hexa chars. I have tried with the code bellow. I think it is ok the hexa conversion, but when I have tried to convert back to decimal notation it does not work, give me other values. Programmers C#, C++ and Java I think could help me.

```
int n = 99;  // 2^6 bits to use 99
int k = 999; // 2^9 bits to use 999

int bits = (n << 6) | (k << 9 << 6); // I'm not sure if it is ok to convert and use with hexa

var hexa = bits.ToString("X"); // I will transmit this hexa to a web service
```

And in a another project, I have a Windows Service to read the hexa from the web service. I can read fine but I do not know how to convert back the hexa value and take the `n` and `k` values, for sample:

```
string hexa = GetFromWebService(); // get from the value from the web service here, its fine

// I will recieve the hexa and get the number in bits
int received = Int32.Parse(hexa, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

// here I need to discover the N and K values... how?
```

How to discover the `n` and `k` values?

### Final solution

```
long v = 123456789456;
string h = v.ToString("X");

// trasmit h value

var data = long.Parse(hexaValueFromService, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

thank you

Comment: Your question is confusing me a bit. Your example `String s = "0101230154V";` does contain 11 chars, but the last char is not decimal. Is this a typo?

Comment: I think he meant 11 as in decimal notion.

Comment: What characters do you allow in the string? Obviously, if you can have  256 options (or more), you cannot encode this in a hexadecimal string of less than 22 characters.

Comment: I update my question guys, I think it is simpler to understand. Tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a typo when you say *"11 decimal characters"* or not because the last character clearly is not a decimal or hexadecimal digit.

If it's a real typo, 11 decimal characters have a maximum value of 99 999 999 999 which fits into a 64-bit int which corresponds to only 16 hex chars. So you can convert the string to `int64_t` (C++)/`long` (C#/Java) and then pass to the other service.

In case that it's not a typo then you can still convert the first 10 decimal digits to a `int64_t` and then pass both the `int64_t` and the remaining character, only 18 hex chars is needed

If you don't want to convert to binary then [densely packed decimal (DPD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Densely_packed_decimal) is a good choice. It packs 3 decimal digits into 10 bits. So 10 digits need 34 bits which takes up 9 hex digits. This works directly on decimal and doesn't need to convert into binary so not only it takes up less space but it's also very quick in conversion back and forth. If you don't need to do arithmetic on the value, this maybe the best choice

Comment: Could you give-me an exemple? I'm really noob with this type of approuch hehe

Comment: as for your string "0101230154V", 0101230154 = 0x000000000608A64A, V = 0x56 ASCII. So you may transfer the string as 0x000000000608A64A560000

Answer (score 1):

An ASCII character takes one byte, or 8 bits.
A Unicode character takes two bytes, or 16 bits.
Therefore that String of 11 chars will either take 11 bytes or 22 bytes depending on CharacterSet.
Try setting the CharacterSet to ASCII, and it will work.
In normal typing, two hexadecimal characters store ONE byte. Therefore, your service has a maximum of 90bits input (10.5 byte)

Comment: "_A Unicode character takes two bytes_" that's not exactly correct. The Unicode encoding UTF-8 encodes a character in 1,2,3 or 4 bytes, UTF-16 in 2 or 4 bytes and UTF-32 encodes every character in 4 bytes.

Comment: I think java uses 16-bit Unicode character set, but correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Yes, internally Java uses UTF-16, so each character is encoded in 2 or in 4 Bytes (low and high surrogate).

Comment: I update my question guys, I think it is simpler to understand. Tks

Comment: Not really, I am even more lost to be honest.

Comment: There is no way to convert back to get the `n` and `k` value from the `received` variable?

Comment: You are setting them, why do you need them back?

Comment: It is in a diferent scope, I mean... the first part is on a remote hardware and it transmit to a web service. I will receive in a windows Service and I need to convert back.

Answer (score 1):

can you ensure that the character will not appear in the first 2 digits? if so, then you can put the integer from the first 2 digits in k.

if you left shift for suppressing the leading '0's while you pass, once you get it you have right shift again to get the original number  rather than parsing the Integer. for example:
if you do this :

(n is 6 bits and k is 9 bits) so, you want combine them into bits (15 bits, 16th bit is sign bit so will not use that)

```
int bits =   (k << 6) | n
```

when you receive, you have to do this to retrieve the values:

```
n = (bits & 0x3F)     // gets rid of k in the first part 0x3F means '0000000000111111'
k = (bits >> 6)       // gets rid of n at the bottom part
```

Comment: Hi friend, thank you for your answer. I'm testing it and the `k` is comming fine, but the `n` not. Why k is 10 bits instead os 9?

Comment: with 9 bits, you can go upto 512. you need 10 bits to go upto 999. changed my answer anyway because we should not use the 16th bit which is sign bit; also need 7 bits to go upto 99.   try now

Comment: Strange, n is `35` and k is `999` (ok). I change the initial values of `n` to `12` and `k` to `452`.. and both comes fine, when `n` is `99` (the max possible value) it comes `35`..

Comment: as I said, you can go upto 63 and 511 with 6 and 9 bits respectively...for 99 and 999 you need 7 and 10 bits respectively. can you use 99 and 99 in n and k ? then you need 7 + 7 = 14 bits and easily be done in int type.  in that case int bits = (k << 7) | n; n=(bits & 0x7F) ; k= bits >> 7

Comment: The max possible value for n is 99 and k is 999. That's the reason I'm trying out with theses values. I have tested this: `int bits = (k << 7) | n;` and to convert: `n= (bits & 255); k = bits >> 7`. I get all values fine but I do not know why `255`, it is because 255 is the 2^7-1 (-1 because sign)?

Comment: the binary of 255 is '0000 0000 0111 1111' (16 bit format). So when you do the bitwise & operation, only the last 7 bits remain - the other 9 bits are turned to zeros. hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Zia, I will approve your awnser, but just more a question, if I have another value `b = 2359` for sample, how could I concat this value to another `n` and `k`, shoul I use `|` operator and `<<` to what? thank you again!

Comment: for concatenation, you should convert the integer to string first and then perform string concatenation. | or << will not help because they do bit manipulation - not string.